# How to call a slot on quit

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots

I want to update my database just before my Qt application closes.

I want something like `connect(this, SIGNAL(quit()), this, SLOT(updateDatabase()))`
One way could be to introduce a quit button, but is it possible to achieve this functionality if user presses `Alt+F4`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use signal [`aboutToQuit()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) instead.

> This signal is emitted when the application is about to quit the main
>   event loop, e.g. when the event loop level drops to zero. This may
>   happen either after a call to quit() from inside the application or
>   when the users shuts down the entire desktop session.
>
> The signal is particularly useful if your application has to do some
>   last-second cleanup. Note that no user interaction is possible in this
>   state.

For example :

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), this, SLOT(updateDatabase()));
```

Comment: Right. But my mainwindow inherits QMainWindow, which has no SIGNAL aboutToQuit().

Comment: `aboutToQuit()` belongs to `QCoreApplication` or `QGuiApplication`.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to do it, not `aboutToQuit()` signal, but to **re-implement** the `closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)`. You can call you slot before the statement `event->accept()`;

like this:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    call_your_slot_here();
    // accept close event
    event->accept();
}
```